# How are the Directory Authorities chosen?

Tags: relays, directory

There are 9 [directory authority servers](https://atlas.torproject.org/#search/flag:authority). Six of them are located in the EU, and three in the USA. There is not a single authority in Asia, Africa, Australia or South America.

What is the reason for this distribution?

Could this distribution cause any disadvantages for relays or users outside of Europe or America? Like higher latency, or lower bandwidth for relay measurements?

Answer (score 2):

> Could this distribution cause any disadvantages for relays or users outside of Europe or America? Like higher latency, or lower bandwidth for relay measurements?

Yes, but for most cases this wont be seen, the consensus is not that large to download (2mb). And there is a [proposal](http://ea5faa5po25cf7fb.onion/projects/tor/ticket/13339) made in a GSoC project that seeks to make it less expensive for clients with low bandwidth to get the consensus.

Comment: But isn't that because of the general distribution of relays rather than just the authorities? I do not believe you're very likely to fetch the consensus from an authority anyway but rather from a regular relay that has it cached.